# Get previous 3 months data based on current date - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I get the previous 3 months data using SQL statement? for example if the current date is 01/01/2012, so how to get the data for December, November, October 2011 ?

Please someone guide me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
WHERE mydate BETWEEN DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH) AND now()
```

Or if you want to stay within the months

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
WHERE MONTH(mydate) BETWEEN MONTH(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)) AND MONTH(now())
  AND YEAR(mydate) BETWEEN YEAR(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)) AND YEAR(now())
```

This latter version will run much slower, because it cannot use an index for `mydate` however.

Comment: your solutions works fine if the current date = 01/01/2012. But when i change the current date into 21/09/2011, I got zero result.

Comment: The date needs to be in yyyy-mm-dd format, use '2011-09-21' as your date.

Comment: ok now i used the first solution. but that solution always return 2 rows instead of 3 why? I already change the date into yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: Change the select into `select *, DATE_SUB(<date here>, INTERVAL 3 MONTH) as date_used ...` Then you can see which date is actually used.